# Querying dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I have some dates saved as `VARCHAR(25)`. I'm trying to write a query to search for Date1 but it's not doing it simply because the date is not saved as `DATE` or `DATETIME`. Can someone help?

This is what I've been trying...

```
Select * from tblAd1
where date1 = '9/12/2016'
```

EDIT:
My mistake - it was happening when I tried to do `ORDER BY` Date1 is when it wasn't doing it properly.

```
Select * from tblAd1
order by date1
```

Comment: Your analysis is incorrect.   If there were any rows that had the varchar value '9/12/2016' in the `date1` column, this query would return them.

Comment: try `CONVERT` or `CAST` to format it correctly.

Comment: I'm looking at the date in the table and see that there is a date '9/12/2016' however when I run my query it doesn't return any records

Comment: In which format are the dates stored in tha varchar column? Is it the same Format as `'dd/MM/yyyy'`? Btw. it is a bad idea to store date in stings, just because of that.

Comment: Can you add a script that reproduces this result?   If you're right then you must have a defective version of SQL Server.

Comment: Woah... why is this downvoted? The question is crisp clear, there's sample code given... wth?

Comment: I see that you removed the single quotes in an edit.   That is the problem.  You need the single quotes around the date string.

Comment: @TabAlleman my mistake - please see edit.

Comment: @Crono - i don't know either. But sometimes you seem to ask a question that needs a simple answer (in this case I havent used cast before) but instead someone downvotes it  and then my account gets locked.

Comment: Actually the question was obfuscated.   A query was posted that couldn't possibly produce the results the OP claimed.   Turns out the actual problem was caused by something that wasn't included in the question at all.   Questions seeking debugging help (why isn't this working?) need to include the minimum information needed to reproduce the issue.   That this was obviously missing was the reason for my downvote, personally.

Comment: About your edit... `CAST` / `CONVERT` still could help you with the ordering.

Comment: Why do you store dates in a varchar column? Is there no date data type available?

Comment: @jarlh Someone created it a while back i'm just querying dates but kept getting incorrect data.

Comment: I would highly recommend that you push people around at your job so that this nonsense of a db design gets fixed. Especially if it's still getting updated. You never know when someone will insert a value that won't convert. Or worse yet: a value that will convert to the WRONG date!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `CAST` or `Convert`

```
Select * 
from tblAd1
where cast(date1 as date) = '2016-09-12'
```

Even though it possible to search, you should store dates in `DATE` datatype rather storing in `Varchar`. Since you are storing date in `varchar` type there are more changes to store bad dates which leads to error when converting it to `date`. Also this avoid usage of any `index` present in `date1` column

Comment: @Bobski Errors isn't even the worst case scenario. You could end up with values being casted as an incorrect date. Depending on how sensitive that information is, you may cause unsuspected mayhem in your app because '01/01/16' was casted to january 16th, 1901 rather than january 1st, 2016. Take Prdp's advice and have this fixed asap before you do any more development over this.

Comment: @Crono - I will get on it. For the most part these dates are added for AddedON column - just to see when the record was added. In this i needed to order by the date added - but you are absolutely correct. I have no idea why someone didn't enter is as date or datetime anyway just like every other date column.